# Datatable same duplicate rows on each page problem

Tags: datatable, pagination

I am using Datatable and I have a problem that data coming from the server-side is coming on both the pages as shown in the pic [First Pic]

[Second pic]

When I go to the second page ( see pagination page) then also I get the same 12 records as on the first page of pagination.
And here is my code ajax-server-side2.js and orders2.php

```js
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    "use strict";
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
/*!******************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ../demo3/src/js/pages/crud/datatables/data-sources/ajax-server-side.js ***!
  \******************************************************************************/

var KTDatatablesDataSourceAjaxServer = function() {

    var initTable1 = function() {
        

        // begin first table
        var table=$('#my-datatable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,   
            searchDelay: 500,
            paginate: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            searching: true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'orders/order-func.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    // parameters for custom backend script demo 
                    
                },
                
            },
            columns: [
                
                {data: 'alerts'}, 
                {data: 'store'}, 
                {data: 'orderDate'}, 
                {data: 'status'}, 
                {data: 'item'}, 
                {data: 'customer'}, 
                {data: 'country'}, 
                {data: 'delivery'}, 
                {data: 'orderTotal'}, 
                {data: 'paid'}, 
                {data: 'picked'}, 
                {data: 'printed'}, 
                {data: 'notes'}, 
                {data: 'tag'}, 
                {data: 'action',responsivePriority: -1},
            ],
            
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    title: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCustomScrollable">'+data+'</a>';
                    },
                },
                
                {
                    targets: -11,
                    title: 'item',
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eg'+data.slice(3)+'" class="btn-popup">'+data+'</a> <?php include("product-modal.php"); ?>';
                    },
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -14,
                    title: '<i class="fas fa-store-alt"></i>',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<i class="fas fa-phone-square-alt"></i>';
                    },
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -13,
                    title: '<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>',
                    
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -6,
                    title: '<i class="far fa-window-maximize"></i>',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green"></i>'; //<i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    },
                    
                    
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -5,
                    title: '<i class="fas fa-archive"></i>',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'; 
                    },
                    
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -4,
                    title: '<i class="fas fa-print"></i>',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>'; 
                    },
                    
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -3,
                    title: '<i class="far fa-clipboard"></i>',
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<i class="far fa-clipboard"></i>'; 
                    },
                },
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -2,
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCustomScrollable1"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>'; 
                    },
                },
                
                
                {
                    
                    targets: -9,
                    title: '<i class="fas fa-globe-asia"></i>',
                    
                },
                
            ],
            
        });
        
        
        
        
    
    }; 

    return {

        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function() {
            initTable1();
        },

    };

}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    KTDatatablesDataSourceAjaxServer.init();
});

/******/ })()
;
//# sourceMappingURL=ajax-server-side.js.map
```

```html
<?php
require '../includes/common.inc.php';
$tag_name='';

if(isset($_POST['del-id']) && $_POST['del-id']!=''){
    
    $selector = get_safe_value($con,$_POST['del-id']);
    $sql = "delete from ".DB_PREFIX."tag where id='$selector'";
    mysqli_query($con,$sql);
}

?>

<html lang="en">
    <!--begin::Head-->
    <head><base href="../">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title><?=__('ORDERS')?></title>
        <?php include(MAIN_PATH.'/includes/top.inc.php')?>
                    <div class="content d-flex flex-column flex-column-fluid" id="kt_content">
                        <!--begin::Subheader-->
                        <div class="subheader py-2 py-lg-4 subheader-solid" id="kt_subheader">
                        <!--begin::Container-->
                            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-sm-nowrap">
                                <!--begin::Info-->
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap mr-2">
                                    <!--begin::Page Title-->
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pills-sm nav-dark-75">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-4 active tab-button" data-toggle="tab" href="#kt_tab_pane_11_1" id="all">All</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-4 tab-button" data-toggle="tab" href="#kt_tab_pane_11_1" id="a">Shipped</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-4 tab-button" data-toggle="tab" href="#kt_tab_pane_11_1" id="b">Ready To Ship</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-4 tab-button" data-toggle="tab" href="#kt_tab_pane_11_1" id="c">Ready To Pick</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link py-2 px-4 tab-button" data-toggle="tab" href="#kt_tab_pane_11_1" id="d">Waiting For Stock</a>
                                        </li >
                                    </ul>
                                    <!--end::Actions-->
                                </div>
                                <!--end::Info-->
                                <!--begin::Toolbar-->
                                <div class="card-toolbar">
                                
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Filter</button>
                                    <!--begin::Dropdown-->
                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline mr-2">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bolder dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <span class="svg-icon svg-icon-md">
                                                
                                            </span>Action
                                        </button>
                                        <!--begin::Dropdown Menu-->
                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-left">
                                            <!--begin::Navigation-->
                                            <ul class="navi flex-column navi-hover py-2">
                                                <!--begin::navi header-->
                                                <li class="navi-header  font-size-sm text-primary pb-2">Actions will apply to 6 filtered orders</li>
                                                <!--End::navi header-->
                                                <div class="separator separator-solid my-3"></div>
                                                <!--begin::navi item-->
                                                <li class="navi-item">
                                                    <a href="#" class="navi-link">
                                                        <span class="navi-text">Print</span>
                                                        
                                                    </a>
                                                    <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
                                                </li>
                                                <!--End::navi item-->
                                                <!--begin::navi item-->
                                                <li class="navi-item">
                                                    <a href="#" class="navi-link">
                                                        <span class="navi-text">Ship</span>
                                                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-left">
                                                        <ul class="navi flex-column navi-hover py-2">
                                                            <li class="navi-item">
                                                            <a href="#" class="navi-link">
                                                                <span class="navi-text">Export</span>
                                                            </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <!--End::navi tem-->
                                                <!--begin::navi item-->
                                                <li class="navi-item">
                                                    <a href="#" class="navi-link">
                                                        
                                                        <span class="navi-text">Export</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                                <!--End::navi item-->
                                                <!--begin::navi item-->
                                            </ul>
                                            <!--end::Navigation-->
                                        </div>
                                        <!--end::Dropdown Menu-->
                                    </div>
                                    <!--end::Dropdown-->    
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-light-warning font-weight-bolder btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addNewModal">Add New</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-light-warning font-weight-bolder btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#upload-modal">Upload</a>
                                </div>
                                <!--end::Toolbar-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--end::Subheader-->
                        <!--begin::Entry-->
                        <div class="d-flex flex-column-fluid">
                            <!--begin::Container-->
                            <div class="container" style="max-width:100%;"> <!--change(apply external css)-->
                                <!--begin::Row-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xxl-8 order-2 order-xxl-1">
                                        <!--begin::Advance Table Widget 2-->
                                        <div class="card card-custom card-stretch gutter-b">
                                            <!--begin::Body-->
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <!--begin::Filter Modal-->
                                                <?php include('filter-modal.php');?>
                                                <?php include('upload-modal.php');?>
                                                <!--end::Tag Modal-->                                               
                                                <form class="form" id="kt_form">
                                                    <div class="tab-content mt-5" id="myTabTables11">
                                                        <!--begin::Tap pane-->
                                                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="kt_tab_pane_11_1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="kt_tab_pane_11_1">
                                                            <!--begin::Table-->
                                                            
                                                            
                                                            <div class="table-responsive-xl" id="default-table">
                                                                <table class="table table-head-custom table-checkable" id="my-datatable" >
                                                                    <thead>
                                                                        <tr>
                                                                            
                                                                            <th ><?= __('Alerts')?></th>
                                                                            <th ><?= __('Store')?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Order Date')?></th>
                                                                            <th ><?= __('Status')?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Items')?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Customer')?></th>
                                                              
                                                                            <th><?= __('country') ?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Delivery') ?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Order total')?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Paid') ?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Picked') ?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Printed') ?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Notes') ?></th>
                                                                            <th><?= __('Tags') ?></th>
                                                                            
                                                                            <th><?= __('Action')?></th>
                                                                        </tr>
                                                                    </thead>
                                                                    
                                                                    
                                                                </table>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <!--end::Table-->
                                                            <!--begin::Tag Modal-->
                                                            <?php include('tag-modal.php')?>
                                                            <!--End::Tag Modal-->
                                                            <!--begin::Tag Modal-->
                                                            <?php include('add-modal.php')?>
                                                            
                                                            <!--End::Tag Modal-->
                                                            
                                                            <?php include('new-store-modal.php')?>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <!--end::Tap pane-->
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                                <!--End::Form-->
                                            </div>
                                            <!--end::Body-->
                                        </div>
                                        <!--end::Advance Table Widget 2-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--end::Row-->
                            </div>
                            <!--end::Container-->
                        </div>
                        <!--end::Entry-->
                    </div>
                    <!--end::Content-->
                    <!--begin::Footer-->
                    <!--doc: add "bg-white" class to have footer with solod background color-->
                    <div class="footer bg-white py-4 d-flex flex-lg-column" id="kt_footer">
                     <!--begin::Container-->
                     <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                       <!--begin::Copyright-->
                       <div class="text-dark order-2 order-md-1">
                         <span class="text-muted font-weight-bold mr-2"><?php 
                         $date = date('Y');
                         echo $date; ?>&nbsp;&copy;</span>
                         <a href="#" class="text-dark-75 text-hover-primary">Company name</a>
                       </div>
                       <!--end::Copyright-->
                       <!--begin::Nav-->
                       <div class="nav nav-dark">
                         <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-15 pr-5"><i class="flaticon-facebook-logo-button icon-2x text-success"
                             aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-0 pr-5"><i class="flaticon-instagram-logo icon-2x text-danger"
                             aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-0 pr-0"><i class="flaticon-twitter-logo-button icon-2x text-info"
                             aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                       </div>
                       <!--end::Nav-->
                     </div>
                     <!--end::Container-->
                   </div>
                    <!--end::Footer-->
                </div>
                <!--end::Wrapper-->
            </div>
            <!--end::Page-->
        </div>
        <!--end::Main-->
        <!--begin::Scrolltop-->
        <div id="kt_scrolltop" class="scrolltop">
            <span class="svg-icon">
                <!--begin::Svg Icon | path:assets/lib/met/media/svg/icons/Navigation/Up-2.svg-->
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1">
                    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <polygon points="0 0 24 0 24 24 0 24" />
                        <rect fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" x="11" y="10" width="2" height="10" rx="1" />
                        <path d="M6.70710678,12.7071068 C6.31658249,13.0976311 5.68341751,13.0976311 5.29289322,12.7071068 C4.90236893,12.3165825 4.90236893,11.6834175 5.29289322,11.2928932 L11.2928932,5.29289322 C11.6714722,4.91431428 12.2810586,4.90106866 12.6757246,5.26284586 L18.6757246,10.7628459 C19.0828436,11.1360383 19.1103465,11.7686056 18.7371541,12.1757246 C18.3639617,12.5828436 17.7313944,12.6103465 17.3242754,12.2371541 L12.0300757,7.38413782 L6.70710678,12.7071068 Z" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
                    </g>
                </svg>
                <!--end::Svg Icon-->
            </span>
        </div>
        <!--end::Scrolltop-->
        <!--begin::Global Config(global config for global JS scripts)-->
        
        <script>
        
        </script>
        
        
        <script>var KTAppSettings = { "breakpoints": { "sm": 576, "md": 768, "lg": 992, "xl": 1200, "xxl": 1200 }, "colors": { "theme": { "base": { "white": "#ffffff", "primary": "#1BC5BD", "secondary": "#E5EAEE", "success": "#1BC5BD", "info": "#6993FF", "warning": "#FFA800", "danger": "#F64E60", "light": "#F3F6F9", "dark": "#212121" }, "light": { "white": "#ffffff", "primary": "#1BC5BD", "secondary": "#ECF0F3", "success": "#C9F7F5", "info": "#E1E9FF", "warning": "#FFF4DE", "danger": "#FFE2E5", "light": "#F3F6F9", "dark": "#D6D6E0" }, "inverse": { "white": "#ffffff", "primary": "#ffffff", "secondary": "#212121", "success": "#ffffff", "info": "#ffffff", "warning": "#ffffff", "danger": "#ffffff", "light": "#464E5F", "dark": "#ffffff" } }, "gray": { "gray-100": "#F3F6F9", "gray-200": "#ECF0F3", "gray-300": "#E5EAEE", "gray-400": "#D6D6E0", "gray-500": "#B5B5C3", "gray-600": "#80808F", "gray-700": "#464E5F", "gray-800": "#1B283F", "gray-900": "#212121" } }, "font-family": "Poppins" };</script>
        <!--end::Global Config-->
        <!--begin::Global Theme Bundle(used by all pages)-->
        <script src="assets/lib/met/plugins/global/plugins.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/met/plugins/custom/prismjs/prismjs.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/met/js/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
        <!--end::Global Theme Bundle-->
        <!--begin::Page Vendors(used by this page)-->
        <script src="assets/lib/met/plugins/custom/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBTGnKT7dt597vo9QgeQ7BFhvSRP4eiMSM"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/met/plugins/custom/gmaps/gmaps.js"></script>
        <!--end::Page Vendors-->
        <!--begin::Page Scripts(used by this page)-->
        <script src="<?= LINK?>/assets/js/site.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/lib/met/js/pages/widgets.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="assets/js/pages/crud/datatables/basic/scrollable.js"></script> -->
        <script src="assets/js/pages/crud/datatables/basic/custom.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/modal/order.js"></script> 
        <!-- <script src="assets/js/search.js"></script>  -->
        <script src="assets/lib/met/plugins/custom/datatables/datatables.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/pages/crud/datatables/data-sources/ajax-server-side2.js"></script>
    <!--    <script src="assets/js/pages/crud/ktdatatable/base/html-table.js"></script> -->
        <script src="assets/lib/met/js/pages/custom/todo/todo.js"></script>
        <!--end::Page Scripts-->
    </body>
    <!--end::Body-->
</html>
```

Comment: There are several hundred lines of code in your question. Are they all directly relevant to the specific problem you are facing? Or can you significantly simplify the question by providing a [mre]?

Comment: When I click on the "run code snippet" button, I get `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. If your code is not intended to be a self-contained runnable unit of JS/HTML/CSS, then you can use a regular code block, instead of a snippet.